# How to get a value from a dialog in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, dialog

I am creating an app and I want to show a dialog for the user which contains a slider to pick a value.

the problem comes here, I want to get the value of that slider which user picked and deal with it.

I am using the dialog as a stateful widget and everything works okay except returning the value as I've mentioned.

---

### **The Widget**

```dart
class Dialog extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DialogState createState() => _DialogState();

  final double val;

  Dialog({this.val,});
}

class _DialogState extends State<Dialog> {
  double value = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    value = widget.val;
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: Slider(
        value: value,
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        onChanged: (va) {
          setState(() {
            value = va;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**show dialog code**

```dart
double vale = 0;

-------

() async {
            await showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) => Dialog(
                val: vale,
              ),
            );
          }
```

Comment: check what return value `showDialog` function returns

Comment: it is null when I print it

Comment: see [showDialog](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDialog.html) and check what value it returns

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can access and use the value that comes from your dialog option like this:

```
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) => Dialog(
    val: vale,
  ),
).then((valueFromDialog){
  // use the value as you wish
  print(valueFromDialog);
});
```

The `.then()`will be triggered after the user selects an option on your Dialog.

Comment: he already have `await showDialog` so no `.then` is needed actually

Comment: My example doesn't use the `await`. If you have a `.then()`, you don't use the `await`, and it works.

Comment: i mean that original poster already has `await showDialog(..)` but he does not use the returned value at all - check his code

Comment: Yes, I saw it. That's why am proposing something different.

Comment: this is exactly the same - either you use `Future.then` or `await` keyword - more here: https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await

Comment: how to return value from the widget to get from showDialog?

Comment: @notworking so did you check the official documentation i gave you? if so, what they say about `showDialog`'s return value?

Comment: worked after wrapping the dialog widget with willpopscope and return aa value with the navigator

Comment: @notworking so now you can simply use `var returnValue = await showDialog(...)` - no need for extra `.then()` in your case

Answer (score 37):

What is missing is that you need to return the value when closing the dialog, like this:

```
return AlertDialog(
  title: Slider(
    value: value,
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    onChanged: (va) {
      setState(() {
        value = va;
      });
    },
  ),
  actions: [
    ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
        child: Text('cancel')),
    ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, value),
        child: Text('confirm')),
  ],
);
```

It will then be returned by the showDialog function as expected as a Future

Answer (score 23):

I can suggest you 2 different ways.
Here's the explanation:

you can use either

#### 1) `Navigator.pop(context, value);`

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: Column(
        children: [
          Slider(
            value: value,
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            onChanged: (va) {
              setState(() {
                value = va;
              });
            },
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 15),
          ElevatedButton(
           // Pass the value you want to return here ---------------|
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, value), //<-----|
            child: const Text('confirm'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

here's how to call it:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            // You can get the returned value here -------------|
            double? val = await showDialog<double>(  //<--------|
              context: context,
              builder: (context) => const DialogOne(),
            );
            print('Dialog one returned value ---> $val');
          },
          child: const Text('Show Dialog One'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

#### 2) Callback function.

```
class DialogTwo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DialogTwoState createState() => _DialogTwoState();
  
  // The callback function with data you want to return -------|
  final Function(double value) onConfirm;      // <------------|     

  const DialogTwo({
    Key? key,
    required this.onConfirm,
  }) : super(key: key);
}

class _DialogTwoState extends State<DialogTwo> {
  double value = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: Column(
        children: [
          Slider(
            value: value,
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            onChanged: (val) {
              setState(() {
                value = val;
              });
            },
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 15),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              // Call the function here to pass back the value -----|
              widget.onConfirm(value);       // <-------------------|
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            child: const Text('confirm'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here's how to call it:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            showDialog<String>(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) => DialogTwo(
                // You can use the callback function like this -------|
                onConfirm: (double value) {       // <----------------|
                  print('Dialog two returned value ---> $value');
                },
              ),
            );
          },
          child: const Text('Show Dialog Two'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

That's it, Hope my answer will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I came here with a similar problem. Though, the answers above are helpful, each of them provides only one piece of info required to get things to work.

First, as stated by the answer of JulienV above, the dialog must **return** the value when it closed:

```
return AlertDialog(
  title: Slider(
    value: value,
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    onChanged: (va) {
      setState(() {
        value = va;
      });
    },
  ),
  actions: [
    ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
        child: Text('cancel')),
    ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(val),// returns val
        child: Text('confirm')),
  ],
);
```

Second (from the answer of xSuperMu), calling code should **consume** the value returned:

```
onPressed: () async {
            double? val = await showDialog<double>(  
              context: context,
              builder: (context) => const Dialog(),
            );
            // do something with val
          },
```

Comment: showDialog returns a Future?